# How to lazily build a cache from spark streaming data

Tags: caching, apache-spark, streaming, union

I am running a streaming job and want to build a lookup map incrementally( track unique items, filter duplicated incomings for example), initially I was thinking to keep one `DataFrame` in cache, and union it with new `DataFrame` created in each batch, something like this

```
 items.foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[String]) => { 
     ...   
        val uf =  rdd.toDF 
        cached_df = cached_df.unionAll(uf) 
        cached_df.cache 
        cached_df.count   // materialize the 
     ... 
    })
```

My concern is that the cached_df seems remember all the lineages to previous `RDD`s appended from every batch iteration, in my case, if I don't care to recompute this cached `RDD` if it crashes, is that an overhead to maintain the growing DAG?

As an alternative, at the beginning of each batch, I load the lookup from parquet file, instead of keeping it in memory, then at the end of each batch I append the new `RDD` to the same parquet file:

```
 noDuplicatedDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("lookup")
```

This works as expected, but is there straight forward way that keep the lookup in memory?

Thanks 
Wanchun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending to Parquet is definitely the right approach. However you could optimize the lookup. If you are okay with the in-memory cache to be slightly delayed (that is, does not have the latest second data), then you could periodically (say, every 5 minutes) load the current "lookup" parquet table in memory (assuming it fits). And all lookup queries will lookup the latest 5 min snapshot.

You could also pipeline the loading to memory and serving of queries in different thread.

Comment: Yes, I load the lookup file once per slide interval. Tathagata, thanks a lot!